# Show and fade div on very fast events

Tags: jquery

I have a form within a webpage which allows the user to make changes to settings. These events trigger an AJAX submit within JQuery and the response from my web application server is almost instantaneous. Until now I have not showed any feedback to the user that a change has been made.

If I add a spinner, its just flashes on the screen for split second which makes it look like a glitch or bug.

I was thinking to add a div with the word SAVED and then fade it in, pause for 2 seconds, and then fade the div the out before finally removing it.

My JQuery is like this:

```
    $("#ControlInfoForm").change(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'control.cfc?method=change',
        data: $("#ControlInfoForm").serializeArray(),
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function (result) {

        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#AJAX-saved').fadeIn("fast");
            // How do I pause here for 2 seconds?
            $('#AJAX-saved').fadeOut("slow");
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("An error has occured.");
        }
    });
});
```

How do I pause for two seconds and fade out? And am I doing it in the right place?

Comment: You have to put the fadeIn call in the beforeSend callback, there's no point in fading in a spinner after the ajax call has completed.

Comment: You should Google jQuery delay animation next time

Comment: As a sidenote, pausing the animation just to show your cool spinner is bad UX, why would the user want to look at a spinner for two seconds, and not the result he's waiting for.

Comment: I using the word "Saved" rather than a spinner

Comment: @adeneo there is no spinner.... im using a div with the word SAVED in it

Comment: Then disregard my comment if your message does not affect the UX in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Call `fadeOut` in callback function of `fadeIn`
2. Use [**.delay()**](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), it set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.

Code

```
$('#AJAX-saved').fadeIn("fast", function () {
    $('#AJAX-saved').delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
success: function (result) {
            $('#AJAX-saved').fadeIn("fast");
           setTimeout(function(){$('#AJAX-saved').fadeOut("slow");},2000);

        }
```

`fadeout` will be executed after 2 seconds

Comment: very good. would have voted as answer but i used Satpal's solution because I saw that first. thanks for your help friend